# Jetpack's BiometricPrompt (androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt) throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt

I'm using `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03` in a test project and when pushing the `negative button` I always get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence androidx.biometric.BiometricFragment.getNegativeButtonText()' on a null object reference
    at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt$1$1.run(BiometricPrompt.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I think this is a library issue which needs to be fixed as the fragment seems to be null or is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
val prompt = BiometricPrompt(activity, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {}
        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {}
        override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {}
})

val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle(title)
        .setSubtitle(subtitle)
        .setDescription(description)
        .setNegativeButtonText(activity.getString(android.R.string.cancel))
        .build()

prompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no, this is definitely not a duplicate as it is related to a special library and correctly tagged...

Comment: it is; a `NullPointerException` is a `NullPointerException` and everybody claims his `NPE` would be something special. The question as it is even lacks the context... are you sure `activity is FragmentActivity`? ever tried setting a regular `String` as negative text?

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, I am / yes, I have. But it is in no case related to the problem --> `mBiometricFragment` is null WITHIN the library when getting the negativeButtonText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported [three months ago](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122054485) as a bug, and it was reported as fixed [two months ago](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122054485#comment10). However, they have not yet released a fresh artifact.

There are some comments in that issue that suggest that "it's a timing thing", and that adding delays can help as a workaround.

Comment: `/* For the case when onResume() is being called right after authenticate, we need to make sure that all fragment transactions have been committed. */ fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` ...this race condition is/was limited to a single situation.

Comment: I fixed it by posting `prompt.authenticate(promptInfo)` 250 ms delayed

Comment: I'm getting something similar, but not the same:
`Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference
androidx.biometric.BiometricFragment$2$1.run (BiometricFragment.java:86)`

Do you know if it's related?

Comment: @neteinstein: It feels similar, so it might have the same cause, but I have no way of knowing if it truly comes from the same bug.

Comment: Already added it to the bugtracker, it is fixed already and will be in the next release

Comment: @neteinstein: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: Yes, I'm validating if it has fingerprint capabilities before invoking it.

Comment: I am facing this issue for few devices.

anyone has idea when this issue comes?


java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt.lambda$sendError$0 (BiometricPrompt.java:490)
  at android.hardware.biometrics.-$$Lambda$BiometricPrompt$HqBGXtBUWNc-v8NoHYsj2gLfaRw.run (Unknown Source:6)